# Goldilocks temperature

Tags: c

I don't want to use the if-statement chain. Can I write the code in a different way? I want to use the smallest amount of if-statements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int temp;

    printf("type a number: "),
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    printf("\n\n");

    if (temp == 18)
    {
        printf("The temperature is normal, stable conditions. \n");
    }
    else if (temp < 5)
    {
        printf("The temperature is too cold. Massive damage. \n");
    }
    else if (temp > 25)
    {
        printf("The temperature is too hot. Massive damage. \n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("The temperature is unstable. This condition can make damages. \n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use less `if..else`? Do you want to obfuscate your code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code; it's concise and easy to understand.

Comment: well, first, if you write `if(...) {` and `} else if (...) {`, `} else {` it will look much better :)

Comment: Short answer: Yes, you can certainly reduce the amount of `if` statements to zero. But you will need to use different code instead, it will just be different or even get worse overall.

Comment: I am doing this program because it's a homework. The teacher said i must use the smallest amount of if-statement. If the code is perfect, i will not change anything.

Comment: If you want to be a smartass, making your teacher sad, you can transform an `if (condition) { code; }` into a `while (condition) { code; break; }` :P

Comment: thank you grek, hahaha yes, my teacher will be sad ;)

Comment: If you want to be a smart ass and and not use _any_ `if` statements, you could use a very long single line with multiple ternary operators

Comment: @StoryTeller no, no, absolutely, just saying that is the first (and only) change I'll do with that code.

Comment: A table of structs describing a temperature interval with a "description", This way you can add an in definite number of intervals/descriptions without changing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comment mentioned the ternary operator, that would be an option. However, with nested ternary operators it's essential to have a well readable formatting. Note that this is **not** better than the if-else. Just different.

```
printf(
    temp == 18
    ? "The temperature is normal, stable conditions. \n"
    : temp < 5
    ? "The temperature is too cold. Massive damage. \n"
    : temp > 25
    ? "The temperature is too hot. Massive damage. \n"
    : "The temperature is unstable. This condition can make damages. \n");
```

A solution which doesn't rely on bad spaghetti-code could involve a helper function that is abstracting the task of printing a text for some given number range. Note, I changed the `5` and `25` numbers in order to compare them as an *inclusive* range rescription.

```
int PrintIfInRange(int temp, int lower, int upper, const char* text)
{
    if (temp >= lower && temp <= upper)
    {
        printf(text);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int temp;

    printf("type a number: "),
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    printf("\n\n");

    if (!PrintIfInRange(temp, 18, 18, "The temperature is normal, stable conditions. \n") &&
        !PrintIfInRange(temp, INT_MIN, 4, "The temperature is too cold. Massive damage. \n") &&
        !PrintIfInRange(temp, 26, INT_MAX, "The temperature is too hot. Massive damage. \n"))
    {
        printf("The temperature is unstable. This condition can make damages. \n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

This second part is less of an answer to your question about *least number of `if` statements* or *smallest amount of code*, but more an addition to show, how the code could be changed to be more expressive about what is happening.

Comment: I will surely fire that developer who will use this code in production.

Comment: Drat, didn't post fast enough for the green check! Damn you @grek40 ;-)

Comment: Terrible code. Don't us that in production code.

Comment: @haccks I'll be careful not to make you my boss :) other than that, I'd probably do something like `WriteIfRange(temp, x, y, text)` function or something completely different. However, I'd first fire the one who is requesting *"smallest amount of if-statement"* in production code.

Comment: the teacher said "the smallest amount of if statement" because she wants the shortest code.

Comment: @Eduardo; Shortest doesn't mean better. Always write clear and detailed program.

Answer (score 4):

One single `if` and you can add an indeterminate number of temperature conditions without adding a single `if`.

And this *code* is very short, the `struct` stuff isn't code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct
{
  int low;
  int high;
  const char *text;
} temperatures[] = 
{
  { 18, 18, "The temperature is normal, stable conditions. \n" },
  { -INT_MAX, 5, "The temperature is too cold. Massive damage. \n" },
  { 25, INT_MAX, "The temperature is too hot. Massive damage. \n" },
};

int main()
{
  int temp;

  printf("type a number: "),
    scanf("%d", &temp);
  printf("\n\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(temperatures) / sizeof(temperatures[0]); i++)
  {
    if ((temp > temperatures[i].low && temp < temperatures[i].high) || (temp == temperatures[i].low && temp == temperatures[i].high))
    {
      printf("%s", temperatures[i].text);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  printf("The temperature is unstable. This condition can make damages. \n");
}
```

Comment: I completely agree that a solution like this is correct for any usage that transcends bad-teacher-requirements.

Comment: You could use `temp >= temperatures[i].low && temp <= temperatures[i].high` instead of two separate expressions.

Comment: @2501 thanks, this was just quickly written code.

Comment: Suggest using `INT_MAX/INT_MIN` rather than 1000/-273.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the messages for this example, which has one `if`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VALUES 5

int main(void) 
{
    char *message[VALUES] = { "too high", "unstable", "stable", "unstable", "too low" };
    int tempers[VALUES] = { 25, 18, 17, 4, };
    int loop;
    int temp;

    scanf("%d", &temp);

    for(loop = 0; loop < VALUES-1; loop++) {
        if(temp > tempers[loop]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("The temperature is %s\n", message[loop]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, for no `if` statements (very pedantically):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const char *NORMAL = "The temperature is normal, stable conditions.";
static const char *COLD = "The temperature is too cold. Massive damage."
static const char *HOT = "The temperature is too hot. Massive damage."
static const char *UNSTABLE = "The temperature is unstable. This condition can make damages."

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int temp;

    printf("type a number: "),
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("%s \n", temp < 5 ? COLD : temp > 25 ? HOT : temp == 18 ? NORMAL : UNSTABLE);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

But really this is just code golfing

Comment: Terrible code. Don't us that in production code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thank you for commenting that on _every. single. answer_... the OP clearly stated that this is for homework. Even for homework it's a pretty redundant request to start with

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why you don't want to use `if` statements despite it make easier for other developers to understand what is the motive of the written code. Using ternary operator in this case will obfuscate the code and make it difficult to read and understand.

I would suggest leave it as it is (with all `if/else` statements) which makes more sense.